# Oracle ORA-29536 on DDL-loading java source into the database

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, ddl

I'm looking into wrapping some java functions in pl/sql but am encountering an ORA-29536 on the colon character in for-loops when loading the java source.
I was hoping to understand why the database has difficulty with this, as it doesn't appear to be misinterpreting the colon and trying to bind, and to get any suggestions on a path forward.
I'd like to avoid refactoring the source to abolish all for-loops, and would like to avoid using the loadjava tool if possible.
Database is 12cR1, with ojdk is 1.6.0_71.

Here's an example.
Given these two trivial hello-world-type classes:

```
public final class HelloWorld {
    public static String greet(final String userName) {
        return "Hello " + userName;
    }
}
```

And:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public final class LoopingTest {
    public static String greet(final String userName) {
        final List<String> emptyList = Arrays.asList(userName);
        for (final String string : emptyList) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        return "Hello " + userName;
    }
}
```

When I compile into the database, the first goes in fine and registers `JAVA SOURCE` and `JAVA CLASS` objects ok (I'm using dynamic SQL and a clob in this example since the eventual target will be >32K characters, with enough `@`, `&`, etc. to complicate escaping in a raw script):

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    '
        CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "HelloWorld" AS 
        public final class HelloWorld {
            public static String greet(final String userName) {
                return "Hello " + userName;
            }
        }
    ';
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But the second fails to import:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    '
        CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "HelloWorld" AS 
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;

        public final class LoopingTest {
            public static String greet(final String userName) {
                final List<String> emptyList = Arrays.asList(userName);
                for (final String string : emptyList) {
                    System.out.println(string);
                }
                return "Hello " + userName;
            }
        }
    ';
END;
/

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29536: badly formed source: Encountered "final String string :" at line 1,
column 195.
```

I wondered if there are any changes I can make to coax oracle into loading this.
If using loadjava is the only way to import I can accept that, but I'd prefer loading in one step DDL if possible.  Thanks

Comment: In 11gR2 (1.5.0_51) it doesn't seem to like the `final String`, although the full error message doesn't list plain `String` as expected either, it seems to compile OK with just that `final` keyword removed. I can't test in 12c right now, is it also the case for you?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole That is interesting. Though the removal of any final keyword makes me sad, that could be a workable compromise. I'm away from my machine for a couple hours, but I'll follow up with whether 12c sees it the same as 11g.

Comment: @AlexPoole Sure enough, the only change required for this to load successfully in 12c as well is dropping the `final` modifier in the loop.  Though I'm admittedly a bit bewildered at `final` causing the trouble and I'd be interested background on why `final` isn't supported here, that clears this hurdle away.  I would accept that as an answer to proximal cause and a viable path forward.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I haven't figured out why this is needed though, or been able to find anything that looks relevant on MoS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle seems to be doing some strange pre-processing on the Java code that is flagging the `final String string` in the for-each loop as a problem. The error isn't coming from the Java compiler - as you'd expect, since this is valid. I can't see anything about this issue, including on My Oracle Support.

It isn't, as @JonHeller noted in an edit comment, anything to do with the string concatenation, but also isn't anything to do with dynamic SQL - in 11gR2 anyway I still see the same ORA-29536 error if I just run the DDL directly from a SQL prompt, using your second code block.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "LoopingTest" AS 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public final class LoopingTest {
    public static String greet(final String userName) {
        final List<String> emptyList = Arrays.asList(userName);
        for (final String string : emptyList) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        return "Hello " + userName;
    }
}
/

Error report -
ORA-29536: badly formed source: Encountered "final String string :" at line 7, column 14.
Was expecting one of:
    "boolean" ...
...
```

As a workaround you can just remove the `final` keyword:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "LoopingTest" AS 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public final class LoopingTest {
    public static String greet(final String userName) {
        final List<String> emptyList = Arrays.asList(userName);
        // remove 'final' to avoid ORA-29536
        // for (final String string : emptyList) {
        for (String string : emptyList) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        return "Hello " + userName;
    }
}
/

Java source LoopingTest compiled
```

Or in your original PL/SQL code:

```
DECLARE
  V_SQL_TEXT CLOB := ' ' ||
                     'CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "LoopingTest" AS ' ||
                     'import java.util.Arrays; ' ||
                     'import java.util.List; ' ||
                     ' ' ||
                     'public final class LoopingTest { ' ||
                     'public static String greet(final String userName){ ' ||
                     'final List<String> emptyList = Arrays.asList(userName); ' ||
                     -- remove 'final' to avoid ORA-29536
                     -- 'for (final String string : emptyList){ ' ||
                     'for (String string : emptyList){ ' ||
                     'System.out.println(string); ' ||
                     '} ' ||
                     'return "Hello " + userName; ' ||
                     '} ' ||
                     '} ';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL_TEXT;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You should consider raising a service request with Oracle, to see if they can explain and/or fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Good suggestion; I'll follow up over at oracle.  If anything interesting comes of it I'll update here.

Comment: Just a follow-up here.  I took your suggestion--SR is in at Oracle and being reviewed.  I'll update with the explanation when it comes in.